# ionic 4 - how to animate transition to root page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm building an Ionic app for the first time and using `routerDirection` transitions so far.

So, how can I animate transition when using the `root` direction? It would be great if I can use flip or slideUp animations.

Is it possible?